# SVN backup batch wont recognize spaces

Tags: svn, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create an SVN backup of my Google docs folder and any folders with a space get truncated at the space

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('svn.exe status C:\Google ^| find "?"') do (svn.exe add "%%i")
svn.exe commit -m "automatic commit"
```

When I break it down and just run

```
svn.exe status C:\Google ^| find "?"
```

The result is

```
  ?       C:\Google\This Is A Test
```

So I echoed it to see why the batch was failing to commit everything

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %i in ('svn.exe status C:\Google ^| find "?"') do (echo %i)
```

and the result was

```
C:\Google\This
```

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to `tokens=1,*` and use `%%j`

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('svn.exe status C:\Google ^| find "?"') do (svn.exe add "%%j")
svn.exe commit -m "automatic commit"
```

The `tokens=2*` is taking the second space delimited value into `%%i` and the remaining in `%%j`

if you `echo %%j` you will see `Is A Test`.